# Current through inductor as a function of lambda

Tags: current, inductor

While reading some introductory text I encountered this symbol, which i know is called lambda but i do not know what it means. I have not taken many advanced math courses yet. I understand the concept of the integrals shown previously but it was always showed as a function of time (t) but in this specific case it is shown as a function of that symbol.
[image]
[image: formula]

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's just a symbol that's different from t. The integral is from 0 to t. I think you could substitute the lambda with x or y or any other symbol and it wouldn't change the meaning

Comment: @BeB00 Thats what I was thinking as well.

Comment: Yes. Not sure why they used \$\lambda\$ when they could have used \$t'\$ or \$\tau\$, though.

Comment: Possibly because \$\lambda\$ is Greek 'L' and \$\tau\$ would confuse with time constant.

Comment: Isn't \$λ\$ the usual symbol for flux linkage? Seems an odd choice for a dummy variable integrated up to \$t\$, which is presumably time.